# find_each or find_in_batches not iterating

Tags: ruby, loops

I got this piece of code:

```
    puts Barrier.where(active:true).where.not(branch_id:nil).find_each.inspect
    puts Barrier.where(active:true).where.not(branch_id:nil).count
    puts Barrier.where(active:true).where.not(branch_id:nil).pluck('id').inspect
    Barrier.where(active:true).where.not(branch_id:nil).find_each do |barrier|
      puts "........................Barrier.........................."
    end
```

and i get this for the first puts:

```
#<Enumerator: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Barrier id: 13, name: "Entrada Pionono", serial_number: "0000000045d83771", access_token: "uf0Nu_bK6y7ikfeUiM4Szg", active: true, access_type: "entry", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 9, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 9, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-04 19:52:13", updated_at: "2019-02-21 11:45:20", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 3, name: "Awesome Entry", serial_number: "nose", access_token: "p7t8xeud04SHFHijHRJ25Q", active: true, access_type: "entry", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 11, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "", app_version: "", peripherals: 9, company_id: 1, created_at: "2018-10-22 22:55:15", updated_at: "2019-03-08 20:20:06", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 17, name: "Salida Pedro de Valdivia", serial_number: "0000000049ce40b7", access_token: "RU_ygZ8QoT-BBc-6OTVjUw", active: true, access_type: "exit", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 10, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 9, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-12 18:06:49", updated_at: "2019-02-15 19:50:00", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 16, name: "Entrada Pedro de Valdivia", serial_number: "00000000e465d46a", access_token: "XNJSfpr_9Gt3deIpAR5Zlw", active: true, access_type: "entry", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 10, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 13, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-12 18:05:52", updated_at: "2019-02-15 19:50:16", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 14, name: "Salida Pionono", serial_number: "0000000015459ed5", access_token: "ju9zMcpx-_3y2gz8Ts-NXQ", active: true, access_type: "exit", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 9, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 9, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-04 19:52:58", updated_at: "2019-02-15 19:50:30", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 12, name: "Salida Zapadores", serial_number: "000000008e846af6", access_token: "O5hFv8QU61oszU3u-9xI0A", active: true, access_type: "exit", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 8, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 9, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-04 19:51:44", updated_at: "2019-02-15 19:51:07", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 10, name: "Salida TVN", serial_number: "00000000fc8317a6", access_token: "0Gmj5mAk_Bh6qEeRNKP01g", active: true, access_type: "exit", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 7, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 9, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-04 19:25:03", updated_at: "2019-02-15 19:51:31", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 9, name: "Entrada TVN", serial_number: "00000000e9e90d38", access_token: "DdPeLD_j8Xz38tcVmv9jew", active: true, access_type: "entry", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 7, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 9, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-04 19:24:41", updated_at: "2019-02-15 19:51:51", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 8, name: "Salida Piramide", serial_number: "0000000043ae8782", access_token: "P_5HTd0IlwQfAbW-Coq5BQ", active: true, access_type: "exit", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 6, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 9, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-04 19:23:59", updated_at: "2019-02-15 19:52:03", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, #<Barrier id: 7, name: "Entrada Piramide", serial_number: "000000006c48e8e1", access_token: "0738sfIqJrdfzPzxyeYaFw", active: true, access_type: "entry", validation_type: "online", branch_id: 6, pulse_span: 1, hardware_version: "Raspberry pi 3, Lector QR, RTC, Parlantes, Lector ...", app_version: "2", peripherals: 9, company_id: 4, created_at: "2019-02-04 19:21:23", updated_at: "2019-02-15 19:52:17", entry_transactions_count: 0, exit_transactions_count: 0, screen_orientation: "portrait", ota_channel: "stable", transbank_terminal_code: nil, nfc_type: "no_type", multiple_tag_readings: false, flags: 0, contactless_delay: 5, external_id: nil, service_type: nil, user_code: nil, emission_point: nil, next_ticket_time: nil, antenna_type: "no_antenna", button_sensibility: 300>, ...]>:find_each(start: , finish: , batch_size: 1000, error_on_ignore: )>
```

for the count i got: `64`

for the pluck('id') i got: `[13, 3, 17, 16, 14, 12, 10, 9, 8, 7, 11, 22, 23, 25, 24, 108, 20, 34, 116, 15, 72, 33, 31, 32, 30, 73, 128, 35, 127, 21, 36, 71, 29, 120, 132, 122, 109, 126, 37, 75, 76, 77, 78, 111, 124, 118, 117, 112, 4, 125, 74, 121, 119, 110, 115, 70, 19, 114, 131, 123, 113, 129, 133, 5]`

Yet i dont get any of the expeted "........................Barrier.........................." prints, what is a possible reason for find_each not iterating (i have almost identical code in other parts of my app that work fine)

Comment: To debug this further, I recommend `puts Barrier.where()....count` and `puts Barrier.where().....pluck('id')`. Maybe this will give some insight to what is happening. (p.s. the `....` is because I'm too lazy to copy/paste the code there. Be sure `count` and `pluck` both have a `.` in front of them.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice added both and commented the prints i got

Comment: I would expect `find_each` to return the records ordered by `id` but the first output doesn't look like that. Do you have any default scopes defined on the model? What does `puts Barrier.where(active:true).where.not(branch_id:nil).to_sql` return?

Comment: @spickermann i got: SELECT "barriers".* FROM "barriers" WHERE "barriers"."active" = TRUE AND "barriers"."branch_id" IS NOT NULL.
No default scopes on Barrier and selects are not orderer by id neccesarily unless you order_by, this is the case for all the query's i have so not surpriced by that

Comment: @spickermann You shouldn't expect any specific ordering from an Active Record query unless it is explicitly stated with an `order_by()` call.

Comment: @Nero I'm at a loss here. It is strange that `count` is 64 and there is a whole list of ids but `for_each()` doesn't output anything. The only reason I can think of `for_each()` not iterating is if the collection has no elements, but you clearly show that there are some.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice furthermore if i use a regular find with the same query and then iterate with an each it works, problem is i can't do that in production since there is a lot of data there.

Comment: sorry, IDK what else to suggest here. The best I can do is upvote. GL with solving this.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I would expect the records to be order by `id asc` because that is the default for `find_each`. Quote from the docs: _It’s not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering work. This also means that this method only works when the primary key is orderable (e.g. an integer or string)._

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for the info. In this particular case, the output of ids is from `.pluck('id').inspect()`, so no `find_each()` there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice But the output from `find_each.inspect` is also not ordered by `id` and it should be.

Comment: @spickermann gotchya...that is definitely strange. I didn't look through that output since it is so long. Lots of strange things going on here that I don't understand.

Comment: Another strange thing: The `find_each.inspect` output only includes 10 records. But the default batch size of `find_each` is 1000, which mean the first batch should already include all 64 records. Perhaps `find_each` was overwritten in the application or by a gem?

Comment: @spickermann i would be inclined to think that about a gem overwritting it, but this particular piece of code is used in several other places in the same app (it works in every other place, but here it does not for some reason)
By the way i think it does have all the 64 records not just 10 i think that's why it has the ... at the end, probably just how it decided to print it

Comment: it was a flag called loop in barrier, not 100% sure why that is making the find_each behave like that but that's it, thanks for the help!